# How to use translate in python

Tags: python

import os

def rename_files():

```
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Engismail\Desktop\prank")

saved_path = os.getcwd()

print("Current Work Directory is"+saved_path)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Engismail\Desktop\prank")

          for file_name in file_list:
```

os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))

```
os.chdir(saved_path)
```

rename_files()

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> Return a copy of the string in which each character has been mapped through the given translation table. The table must be an object that implements indexing via **getitem**(), typically a mapping or sequence. When indexed by a Unicode ordinal (an integer), the table object can do any of the following: return a Unicode ordinal or a string, to map the character to one or more other characters; return None, to delete the character from the return string; or raise a LookupError exception, to map the character to itself.

So you can pass a dictionary from unicode ordinal (which you can find using `ord`) to the output string to translate the characters

```
>>> s = "lol"
>>> ord("l")
108
>>> s.translate({108:"w"})
wow
```